# rewrite my page to some thing seo friendly urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello I have three different pages on which products are listed. when you click a product you will go to

```
product?m_id=1
price?m_id=1
repairing?m_id=1
```

I have a slug column in database present and I want these three pages to rewrite like this by apache rewrite

```
product/slug
price/slug
repiaring/slug
```

I have used this rewrite rule but its not working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ product.php?slug=$1
```

Comment: You're replacing slug with ID I suspect. You might need to change the select query to find product by slug instead of ID.

Comment: Try `RewriteRule "(.*)product/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$" $1product.php?slug=$2` And remove `RewriteBase`

Comment: Hello i have changed ID to slug and used the rewrite rule you mentioned. It worked but now css style has stopped working... my css is like this <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: @tanveer Use the `<base href="/">` tag in your html/php pages

Comment: @hjpotter92 I have used base tag, all the font, images , colour and background came back but the layout is still not cameback. it is still zig zag....

Comment: @hjpotter92 the base issue is solved as I moved the tag to the second line after <head> region.

Comment: @alok patel now one more question if i want the pages to show like this page one as /slug and page two as /slug and page three as /slug instead of product/slug
price/slug
repiaring/slug       how can we do it

Comment: @tanveer Your apache server will never know whether `/data` is a price, a product or repairing thing.